# Invalid region for small angles. To Element Mesh. Finite element method

Tags: mesh, finite-element-method

I would like to mesh the region below in order to use it for a calculation by means of NDSolve. Could anyone help me to discretize this region for NDSolve using. Thank you very much.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];

Rwg=7.0; RLiner=8.0; RRib=8.5; RExt=9.0; Theta1=0.0227; Theta2=0.00916; 

Ω=ImplicitRegion[
    !(x^2 + y^2>RLiner^2 && x^2 + y^2< RRib^2 && 0<y<x*Tan[Theta2])&&
 (y>=0 && x^2 + y^2>=Rwg^2 && x^2 + y^2<=RExt^2 && y<=x Tan[Theta1]),{x, y}];


Show[ RegionPlot[Ω], ImageSize -> 300]

ToElementMesh[Ω,MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0001]["Wireframe"]
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, you've done well to post your code, and we'd love to help, but we can't really check the code without values for all those constants.

Comment: The constants values are:

Rwg=7.0;
RLiner=8.0;
RRib=8.5;
RExt=9.0;

Theta1=Pi/4;
Theta2=Pi/8;

Thank you. I would be very grateful for your reply.

Comment: When I enter [this code](http://pastebin.com/raw/tvepM8PS), I get [this result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/y7rjG.png), so I have no error with version 10.3.1.  What version are you using?  The mesh is extremely fine and I assume memory intensive, what happens if you change it to `MaxCellMeasure -> 0.1`?

Comment: Antony, please use the edit link right under your question to add those details in the question itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With those values, the code works, but if you please try to use the following values of Theta1 and Theta2, the code does not work anymore:

Theta1=0.0227
Theta2=0.0091

Comment: Not sure why doesn't work, but `ToElementMesh@
 DiscretizeRegion[\[CapitalOmega], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0001]` maybe is useful...

Comment: With the small angles `ImplicitRegion` is generating an invalid region. Antony please edit the question to explain the actual problem. The subject ought to be changed as well since this doesn't really directly relate to `ToElementMesh`

Comment: Ok, George. Thank you

Comment: @george2079 - can you reproduce the error here?  I'm using the updated values for `Theta1` and `Theta2`, I can't get an error using either the original conditional or your modified form below.

Comment: Don't you just hate it when the OP changes the problem!

Answer (score 4):

Look at the boundary mesh generated for the region:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
Rwg=7.0;RLiner=8.0;RRib=8.5;RExt=9.0;Theta1=0.0227;Theta2=0.00916;
\[CapitalOmega]=ImplicitRegion[!(x^2+y^2>RLiner^2&&x^2+y^2<RRib^2&&0<y<x*Tan[Theta2])&&(y>=0&&x^2+y^2>=Rwg^2&&x^2+y^2<=RExt^2&&y<=x Tan[Theta1]),{x,y}];
ToBoundaryMesh[\[CapitalOmega]]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

You see there is a line at `y==0` which should not be there.

```
\[CapitalOmega][[1]] /. {x -> 8.4, y -> 0}
True
```

If you reformulate the region to:

```
LOWER = -1;
\[CapitalOmega] = 
 ImplicitRegion[! (x^2 + y^2 > RLiner^2 && x^2 + y^2 < RRib^2 && 
      LOWER <= y < x*Tan[Theta2]) && y >= 0 && x^2 + y^2 >= 49.` && 
   x^2 + y^2 <= 81.` && y <= 0.022703899831486306` x, {x, y}]
```

This example works as expected:

```
ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega]]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Now, various version of Mathematica use different (default) algorithms to to discretize regions. Even more so `DiscretizeRegion` and `ToElementMesh` may use different algorithms in the same version. What I have shown here is version 10.4

Comment: Thanks - this method works for version 10.2 as well so it solves OP's problem.  I knew it was a good idea to call in the artillery

Comment: @JasonB, I always thought of myself as being a little more subtle than the artillery ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a bug: for some reason changing the conditional `y<x Tan[]` to `y/x<Tan[]` makes it work:

```
Rwg = 7.0; RLiner = 8.0; RRib = 8.5; RExt = 9.0;
Theta1 = 0.0227
Theta2 = 0.0091
\[CapitalOmega] = 
  ImplicitRegion[! (x^2 + y^2 > RLiner^2 && x^2 + y^2 < RRib^2 && 
       0 < y/x < Tan[Theta2]) &&
    (y >= 0 && x^2 + y^2 >= Rwg^2 && x^2 + y^2 <= RExt^2 && 
      y/x <= Tan[Theta1]), {x, y}];
Show[RegionPlot[\[CapitalOmega]], ImageSize -> 300]
<< NDSolve`FEM`
ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0001]["Wireframe"]
```

note the mesh is so dense the wireframe image is just black.

[image]

here it is with `MaxCellMeasure->0.0025`

[image]

v10.1/Windows.
Minimal example of the issue:

```
 GraphicsRow@Table[
  RLiner = 8.; RRib = 8.5; 
  o2 = ImplicitRegion[
    RLiner^2 <= x^2 + y^2 <= RRib^2 && 0 <= y <= x Tan[Theta2], {x, 
     y}];
  Show[{RegionPlot[o2, PlotStyle -> Red] , 
    Plot[{x Tan[Theta2]}, {x, 0, 9}]},
   PlotRange -> {0, .8}] , {Theta2, {.09, .075}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But, unfourtunately, running your code I have back "The implicit region is not a valid region to plot". Moreover, the region discretizaed does not corresponds to the region I want actually discretized

Comment: @Antony, what version of *Mathematica* are you using?  Please answer this, as it could have a great effect on which answer is right for you.  Also, what about using `DiscretizeRegion@Ω`?

Comment: @george2079 - I can confirm the bug in your minimal example is there in 10.1 but fixed by 10.2.  I can also say that the bug *appears* to be confined to `RegionPlot`.  If you replace the first argument of your `Show` command with `{Plot[{x Tan[Theta2]}, {x, 0, 9}], DiscretizeRegion@o2}` then it seems to work just fine.

Comment: @JasonB: I am using the Mathematica 10.2.
I never used DiscretizedRegion@Ω

Comment: @Antony - Excellent, I can confirm that the code in the original post gives me an error in version 10.2 - now I can try to find a workaround.  I've never used the FEM capabilities for NDSolve, so I don't really know the difference between an `ElementMesh` and a `MeshRegion`

Answer (score 1):

It can sometimes help out if you [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) your implicit description of the region first.

```
ToElementMesh[
  ImplicitRegion[! (x^2 + y^2 > RLiner^2 && x^2 + y^2 < RRib^2 && 
         0 < y < x*Tan[Theta2]) && (y >= 0 && x^2 + y^2 >= Rwg^2 && 
        x^2 + y^2 <= RExt^2 && y <= x Tan[Theta1]) // Reduce // Evaluate,
   {x, y}], MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0001]["Wireframe"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As has been pointed out, it's a very fine mesh.  Here it is with `MaxCellMeasure` commented out:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: the OP changed the angles in the question to ones that cause an error.  Interestingly with these new angles, I get the error **with** the `Reduce` but it runs fine without:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/QHboS.png

Answer (score 1):

This is all very confusing, different versions of *Mathematica* seem to react differently to the different region functions involved here.  What I'm going to write here is only really applicable to version 10.2, I may put a note at the bottom for other versions.

Here is the region,

```
With[{Rwg = 7.0, RLiner = 8.0, RRib = 8.5, RExt = 9.0, 
  Theta1 = 0.0227, Theta2 = 0.00916},
 region = ! (x^2 + y^2 > RLiner^2 && x^2 + y^2 < RRib^2 && 
       0 < y < x*Tan[Theta2]) && (y >= 0 && x^2 + y^2 >= Rwg^2 && 
      x^2 + y^2 <= RExt^2 && y <= x Tan[Theta1]);
 ]
```

We try to create an `ElementMesh` from this region,

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
ToElementMesh[ImplicitRegion[
   region, {x, y}],
  MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0001]["Wireframe"]
```

> During evaluation of In[22]:= ToElementMesh::fememins: The mesh
>   elements are not valid. A set of valid mesh element incidents needs to
>   be positive integers and be able to form a complete sequence starting
>   from 1 to the largest incident present. There are missing incidents; a
>   complete sequence cannot be formed. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[22]:= ToElementMesh::femtemnm: A mesh could
>   not be generated. >>

```
(* $Failed["Wireframe"] *)
```

We try MichaelE2's trick of simplifying the conditionals,

```
ToElementMesh[ImplicitRegion[
   Evaluate@Reduce@region, {x, y}],
  MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0001]["Wireframe"]
```

> During evaluation of In[24]:= ToElementMesh::fememib: The input has or
>   generated an intersecting boundary and cannot be processed. >>
>
> During evaluation of In[24]:= ToElementMesh::femtemnm: A mesh could
>   not be generated. >>

```
(* $Failed["Wireframe"] *)
```

Still no luck.  But if we first create a `MeshRegion` and then convert it to an `ElementMesh`, then it **does** work, even though it still gives some errors.

```
dregion = DiscretizeRegion[
   ImplicitRegion[
    Evaluate@Reduce@region, {x, y}],
   Method -> "Continuation", PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"];
ToElementMesh[dregion, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.0001]["Wireframe"]
```

> DiscretizeRegion::drcm: Method->Continuation not able to resolve all
>   components of dimension less than the embedding dimension 2; these may
>   be omitted from the result. >>
>
> ToElementMesh::femimq: The element mesh has insufficient quality of
>   -20.1137. A quality estimate below 0. may be caused by a wrong ordering of element incidents or self-intersecting elements. >>

[image]

### Edit

As shown in this screenshot, I only get this error in version 10.2, not in 10.1 or 10.3

[image]